# Powershell error, issue specifying pathways/drives

Tags: powershell, csv, path, import-csv

I am getting a weird error. When I run the below, it gives me this error below. The name of the file, from the $inputfolder, is correct, but the file path is changed the *current drive*, not what I defined as the $inputfolder. Which is why it "cannot find the file."

**Could not find file 'C:\path\of\current\drive\batch.csv'.**

When I move my .ps1 to the $inputfolder it works. I don't know what I did wrong. Variables are defined.
**Also**, the $outputpath is not working. The done.csv file is created in the input folder.

```
$inputfolder = 'C:/path/to/folder/'
$inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder
$outputpath = Join-Path $inputfolder 'done.csv'
Import-Csv $inputobject | select COLUMN1,COLUMN1 | Export-Csv -Path $outputpath -NoTypeInformation
```

EDIT: complete error report; again, "path\of\current\drive" is the location I have the folder where the .ps1 is in, and even though I defined my variables it only works properly when I move the .ps1 to the $inputfolder.

```
Import-Csv : Could not find file 'C:\path\of\current\drive\batch.csv'.
At C:\path\of\current\drive\myscript.ps1:9 char:1
+ Import-Csv $inputobject | select COLUMN1,COLUMN2 | Export-Cs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Comment: Use the other slash, those are front slashes `/` and paths in windows uses the backslash \

Comment: Most contexts that use pathnames in Windows take either `/` or `\` as the path separator; `cmd.exe` does not because it uses `/` instead of `-` as the switch indicator.

Comment: As far as the output csv being put in the input folder, it's doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin unfortunately changing the "/" to "\" is giving the same error..

Comment: Please paste the EXACT and COMPLETE error report.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin done

Comment: I was able to replicate this. Very strange, but when passing the Childitem object, it seems to only pass the file name. I couldn't even figure out how to retrieve the directory. You can just append the two strings, though. `Import-Csv "$inputfolder/$inputobject"` Does this help?

Comment: @MacroPower - Not necessary; see my answer below.

Comment: I see, I must have missed that param? Feels pretty bad.

Comment: @MacroPower - It's not intuitive; it took a bit of experimentation to discover this, plus piping a file object to `Get-Member`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Yeah, I normally use `$x | Select *`. The info is right there, but I got hung up on VersionInfo.

Comment: @MacroPower - Yes, `Select-Object -Property *` will also work, and is also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-ChildItem` returns a set of (in this case, since you are looking at the filesystem) file *objects*, not file *names*. When you pass an array of file objects to `Import-CSV` (or `Get-Content`), it uses the `Name` property, which does *not* include the path. With no path, it assumes that you wish to look in the current directory. The solution for this is to pass not `$inputobject`, but `$inputobject.fullname`, which includes the path of the file object(s).

This is a common misperception among people familiar with text-based interfaces, such as `CMD.EXE` or the various UNIX/Linux shells such as `bash`. Those older shells pass text through the pipeline; PowerShell passes actual objects, and you need to know the actual structure of your incoming data.

There is good information about the PowerShell pipeline from [`Get-Help about_pipelines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines). You can also find out about the structure of a particular PowerShell object by piping it to [`Get-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member).

Answer (score 0):

These commands:

```
$inputfolder = 'C:/path/to/folder/'
$inputobject = Get-ChildItem $inputfolder
```

returns all file in directory 'C:/path/to/folder/'
Are you sure you want to process all files? Maybe even not .csv files?

I would suggest rather to use:

```
$inputfolder = 'C:/path/to/folder/'
$inputobject = Get-Item "$($inputfolder)*.csv"
```

These will collect only the csv files.

And as Jeff wrote, you'll have to use the fullname properties of the input and output objects, so your last command should look like:

```
$inputobject | foreach-object {
Import-Csv $_.fullname | select COLUMN1,COLUMN1 | Export-Csv -Path $outputpath.fullname -NoTypeInformation}
```

And please keep in mind that your $onputobject is not a single file, but a collection of files! The Export-CSV can not "Append" to existing file, so either you have to specify the -Force to it, this way you'll have the result from the last file processed, or you have to be sure the $inputobject collection contains exactly one file, or else the second execution of Export-CSV will stop and promt for confirmation of overwriting the existing file.

Comment: [`Export-Csv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) most certainly can append to an existing file, using the `-Append` switch; see the link on the command name in this comment.

Comment: additionally, `$outputpath` is _not_ a file object, but a string; as such, it does not need any member references to cause the output to be placed where desired.